# What is the source of Cisco AnyConnect Routing Table Entries

Tags: cisco-vpn

When I start Cisco AnyConnect and then run the route print command on Windows, I see that there are around one hundred entries for various networks.  I'm guessing that my company owns or controls all these networks. Anyway, where does Cisco AnyConnect get the list of networks to set up in the routing table?  Does every company that uses Cisco AnyConnect have a server that maintains a list of their networks?  What keeps a company from listing networks that they don't own? Finally, how does Cisco AnyConnect end up owning the routing table in a way that prevents me from being able to modify it?

Comment: AnyConnect gets its instructions from the company firewall. If the company sets the firewall to disable split-tunneling (split-tunneling is a security risk to the company), then you cannot change the routing table until you quit running AnyConnect.

Comment: Probably a Cisco firewall/router or VPN device. (Cisco ASA/ASAv for example)